# No muestra mensaje Toast en validacion Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Buenos días

Ya estoy en los últimos pasos del desarrollo de la app en android studio, solo que ahora me encuentro con una duda, lo que pasa es que cuando ejecuto mi webservices y mando datos para que se graben en mis sistema pero este me regresa un error, es ahí donde estoy confundido, por que yo estoy haciando una validación con un `IF` que si me regresa ok el webservices me mande un mensaje `Toast` de que se guardaron los datos, y en el else un mensaje de error, pero cuando le doy click en el botón guardar no me muestra mi mensaje de error,
les dejo mi código para ver si es que estoy haciendo bien mi validación.

Método Grabar datos, en el return Resultado me regresa la respuesta mi webservices del error, ese error es el que quiero mostrar un Toast

```
 public static String GrabarCxCP(int Recurso,
                                     int Modulo,
                                     int Operacion,
                                     int Documento,
                                     int OrigenId,
                                     int OrigenDocumento)
    {

        String resultado = "";
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://oncontrol.no-ip.net:9020/", "GrabarCXCP");
        request.addProperty("Recurso", Recurso);
        request.addProperty("Modulo", Modulo);
        request.addProperty("Operacion", Operacion);
        request.addProperty("Documento", Documento);
        request.addProperty("OrigenId", OrigenId);
        request.addProperty("OrigenDocumento", OrigenDocumento);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.implicitTypes = false;
        // Set output SOAP object
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        // Create HTTP call object
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 7000);

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
            // Invoke web service
            androidHttpTransport.call("http://oncontrol.no-ip.net:9020/GrabarCXCP", envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            resultado=response.toString();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Assign Error Status true in static variable 'errored'


            e.printStackTrace();
        }

         return resultado;
    }
```

El método `OnPostExecute`  hago mi `if` para que me muestre los mensajes ya sea de error o de que se ejecutó correctamente:

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String Resultado) {
            super.onPostExecute(Resultado);

            if ((Resultado.equals("OK")))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Datos Guardado Correctamen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error en el Wbservices", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

Comment: En el `if` tienes `Resultado`  con la letra "r" en mayúsculas, arriba la tienes en miúsculas, ¿Es error de código o error al copiar tu código acá?

Comment: el de abajo es el codigo que tengo en mi metodo de onpostExecute y el de arriba el es return de mi motodo

Comment: ¿haz puesto un breakpoint para verificar que esta entrando en el postexectue?

Comment: si pero no entra.. no veo que entre... pero aun asi si me muestra el mensaje de datos guardados correctamente

Comment: @HugoRodriguez cual es la definición del Asynctask, ese me parece es seguramente el problema : AsyncTask<?,?,?> esa puede ser una causa por la cual no llama onPostExecute()

Comment: Te recomendaria usar Handlers para evitar este tipo de problemas: Tutorial de Google

Son utiles para comunicar actividades y servicios como en tu caso lo cual comunicaria tu AsyncTask con la actividad que lo este ejecutando

Answer (score 1):

No se esta llamando el `onPostExecute()` puesto que probablemente tu `Asynctask` no tiene una definición correcta:

```
AsyncTask<?,?,String>
```

El último párametro debe ser tipo `String` para que llame sin problemas a tu método:

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String Resultado) {
            super.onPostExecute(Resultado);

            if ((Resultado.equals("OK")))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Datos Guardado Correctamen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error en el Wbservices", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

otro problema podría ser que el doInbackground() esta retornando un valor null y no un int como esta definido, por esa razón no llama onPostExecute().

Comment: este es el parametro mi Asynctask

Comment: AsyncTask<Void,Integer,String>

Comment: y el valor de retorno de doInBackground no es un valor null? debe ser un int.